# calculated app size not showing correct in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, filesize

My app has some content dumping in document folder periodically. And i have used the below code to calculate my total app consumed memory size. But i see its different from what i see from settings\usage. My code shows very less memory. I am not able to track where i am going wrong in calculating/ or have i missed folder paths.

I have calculated my app size as follows:

```
NSString *folderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *filesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]      subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
NSEnumerator *filesEnumerator = [filesArray objectEnumerator];
NSString *fileName;
unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;

while (fileName = [filesEnumerator nextObject]) {
NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] error:nil];
fileSize += [fileDictionary fileSize];
};
```

Comment: Are you considering the content in temp / caches / library ?

Comment: @Wain......./var/mobile/Applications/81D-D8348/Documents/

Comment: So, depending on what you're using it for, is it not ok to tell the user how much data could be deleted, and iOS tell the user how much deleting the app will save?

Comment: my code calculation is showing wrong size when compared to iPhone setting>usage>myapp size

Answer (score 1):

The above code returns the *actual file size*. The value shows in the settings/usage shows the *allocated size*. The *allocated size* shall be more than the actual size.

That's why your calculated value and the setting/usage values are not matching.

If you need to access the allocated size of a file please use NSURLTotalFileAllocatedSizeKey in NSURL class.  There is no methods/ property available in **NSFileManager** class to get the *allocated size* [As far as i know].

Please go through details of *File Property Keys* of the NSURL class.

FYI: We shall get permission error if you try to access the */Library/Caches/Snapshot* folder in Home directory of sanboxed app.

This may be helpful to you.